# Does Job 38:13-14 say that God sees the earth "as a clay seal"?

Tags: hebrew, hebrew-bible, job

[image]

Is G d seeing the earth as one big clay/wax seal 
or is He being misleading to suggest that it looks this way
or is He just operating within the cosmology of those alive then despite it conflicting with modern scientific cosmology
or is the text saying something completely different 
(or is the earth not in fact a sphere?)

> “so that it could take hold of the edges of the earth and shake the wicked out of it? Then the earth is changed like clay under a seal, until its colors are fixed like those of a garment.”
>   ‭‭Iyov (Job)‬ ‭38:13-14‬ ‭CJB‬‬

.

> “That it might take hold of the ends of the earth, And the wicked be shaken out of it? "It is changed like clay under the seal; And they stand forth like a garment.”
>   ‭‭Job‬ ‭38:13-14‬ ‭NASB‬‬

Comment: What is the picture for ?

Comment: To show a clay seal, how the edges stand up like a garment and how the center is flat and thereby illustrate the description of the earth and it’s edges that the Creator describes to Job in the verse

Comment: Please don't write "G d". God is not, and cannot be, offended by the letter "o".

Comment: You can improve this question, which explains the downvotes. Is God "misleading"? The God of the topic of this forum, Bible, doesn't do that. This sentence shows lack of research or familiarity with the Bible (Num 23:19, 1 Sam 15:29, 2 Sam 22:31, Prov 30:5, James 1:13). If you already understand this, you could rephrase it to say, "How is He not being misleading...?"

Comment: I think the question is fine. God doesn’t lie and doesn’t mislead. So is He describing the earth or saying something different. I think people are experiencing cognitive dissonance and it’s messing with their head, so they simply down vote it because they are not willing to struggle with the question and explore it fully. Whether or not there is an answer is beside the point. I’m asking if this is what the text is saying not whether God is being misleading. But to deny what it’s saying is to say God lied, so explain what it means then without changing the text.

Answer (score 2):

### The Edges of the Earth

It might help to read the Hebrew again:

> לאחז ב**כנפות** הארץ וינערו רשעים ממנה׃

Now this would most neutrally read in English:

> that [it] may take hold of the earth by its **extremities,** so [that] the evildoers may be shaken out of it?

As you can see, the generic word meaning '**wings**' (Gn. 1:21) or '**edges**' (Lev. 15:38) is not the kind of thing you want to base a *shape* of the earth on, inasmuch as the word is not about a shape, but function. It could just as easily be translated, 'both sides.'

This could even be an allusion to some kind of metaphorical 'sieving' action performed by the sun, since it appears from the immediate context that the sun shines upon the earth at dawn, symbolic of the **revealing** and **exposing** of evildoers (who presumably do their evil in the 'darkness'). This explains the '**emboss**' language of which both the [clay seal](https://blog.stampsdirect.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/shutterstock_92693746.jpg) and [embroidered clothing](https://i.pinimg.com/564x/69/5b/ce/695bcecea388f9c2d63f58aad200addc.jpg) are chief cultural examples. That is, the evildoers and their wickedness is brought to light by the dawning of the sun, here described as God's intimate partner in executing divine justice.

### Wise "As" Serpents

Another example is when Jesus says that we are to be 'wise' as serpents and 'simple/innocent' as doves (Matt. 10:16). Now doves are not necessarily innocent (animals can't sin). Neither are serpents any smarter or wiser than any other creature (that is detectable, at least). A serpent symbolizes craftiness, wittiness, etc. only in that it is characterized by its legless slithering around, almost deceptive, crafty, witty. Hence this 'craftiness' is epitomic of the virtue of wisdom. A dove symbolizes purity and simplicity and innocence because of how white it is, untarnished in soul, unconcerned with the evils that transpire below the peaceful paths of its flight. So it's easy to see how these became symbols of these respective virtues of wisdom and purity.

This doesn't mean we all have to grow wings and long slithery tails because serpents have tails and doves have wings. Obviously not. It means doves epitomize simplicity: and therefore 'be simple as doves' has the meaning 'strive for the highest degree of purity [i.e. as symbolized by the dove].'

So the take away from this is that similes and metaphors are not about describing literal resemblance, but describing the activity and prerogatives of God in anthropomorphic ways and through analogy. For example, Jesus makes the earth His footstool—not that it is like a chair with legs and gold around the edges and a velvety cushion on top, but simply that He rules over, and makes everyone subject to, Himself, symbolized by their placement under His feet, below Him.

Comment: Loved your response! It just needed an image of "a chair with legs and gold around the edges and velvety cushion on top" orbiting the sun. ;-)

Comment: Haha, yes! Quite the image.

Comment: I like that idea let’s indeed look at the Hebrew. כָּנָף You speak of wing, let’s call it a wing. Of the אֶרֶץ so now we have the wings of the earth. It’s a contrasting verse, comparing the wings of the earth with? חֹמֶר clay/mire חוֹתָם signet seal. The limiting factor is they have to have commonality otherwise it’s not a comparison. So the wings of the earth must appear like a clay signet seal. Wings are used can denote extremities, or quarters, the wings of the orchestra or building. The earth has four corners or wings. And these extremity are likened to the excess clay from a signet seal

Comment: As you described the earth as a foot stool or under foot, (which if heaven is above the earth, then literally the earth is what it’s standing on, but that’s an entirely different discussion) unless you can produce evidence where a clay signet seal is representative of an idiom in ancient texts that I can look up, you have to compare earth’s wings with a clay signet seal and it’s clay excesses standing up enveloping around like a garment. When you have such documentation please send me the references that I may seeking out for myself. Thank you

Comment: "they have to have commonality otherwise it’s not a comparison" I thought I noted that there *was* a commonality—the embossed features of a garment, and a seal respectively. You're insisting it goes beyond this commonality for some other reason, when there is no need to. The garment and the seal are images of the resultant effect of God's shaking the earth, and are not in parallel with it.

Comment: There is more than one kind of simile one can use: "I punched like a kangaroo" means your punch resembled that one might observe from a kangaroo. Another kind of simile is one where other than superficial resemblance is intended: "I punched like a bear." Bears don't punch—but my punch, hyperbolically speaking, had the might of a bear. It's not difficult to distinguish between these two kinds of things, especially when things like 'God uses the earth as a FOOT stool' are said, when God doesn't have a literal body or feet.

Answer (score 1):

When God rebukes Job out of the storm and challenges his ignorance and presumption, He uses figures of speech and paints word-pictures to illustrate man's impotence against the Creator's power and sovereign right to rule, to control and to bring judgment on the wicked:

> Have you ever given orders to the morning, or shown the dawn its place, that it might take the earth by the edges and shake the wicked out of it?  The earth takes shape like clay under a seal; its features stand out like those of a garment.  The wicked are denied their light, and their upraised arm is broken (Job 38:12-15 NIV).

In other words, the dawn brings light to the planet and as it does so, the darkness is forced to retreat.  The wicked come out at night, when it is dark, but have to beat a hasty retreat when their evil deeds are exposed by God's light.

The New Testament identifies Christ Jesus as the light of the world:

> In him was life, and that life was the light of men.  The light shines in the darkness, but the darkness has not understood it" (John 1:4).
>
> This is the verdict: Light has come into the world, but men loved darkness instead of light because their deeds were evil.  Everyone who does evil hates the light, and will not come into the light for fear that his deeds will be exposed" (John 3:19-20).

The illustration used in Job is not about the shape of the planet we live on.  It's about  the light of dawn chasing away the darkness of night and bringing contrast to the contours of the planet we live on.  It's a beautiful word-picture.

Comment: So G d doesn’t care to be accurate and misleading, He it more interested in being poetic and conveying ideas using non existent realities like a flat earth mimicking a wax seal. I respect your opinion. Is there a reason G d chooses to be misleading? Is it because details don’t matter, or because He doesn’t know any better or because the poetry fit better using unreal examples? Curious why you think G d would do such a thing. Could you speak to motivation at all?

Comment: Curious why the Creator including poetic language in his scriptures leads you to assume that that makes him inaccurate and misleading. I'm curious to know what you would thus make of the poetic Song of Songs, or many of the Psalms. You do know that the book of Job makes the point that humans are inclined to ask the wrong questions, and the section you ask about is dealing with the folly of that? The Creator is almost being sarcastic in his response to wrong human ideas. He isn't dealing with the shape of the planet. Was your response to Lesley's reasonable answer either necessary or kind?

Comment: @Mr Constantin - The answer to your question is NO, and I stand by my answer without apology or excuse, even if you don't like it.

Comment: @Anne necessary yes, kind likewise. Unlike the songs of Solomon this is a direct quote from the Creator. He poetically calls the earth resembling a seal but apparently failed to see that others would struggle to see how poetry trumps truth and facts. If I’m poetically describing a leaf, would it be fine to poetically describe an egg but refer to a leaf? Likewise if the earth is being describe poetically, would it be fine to poetically describe it as a wax seal but refer to the shape of the earth? Wouldn’t it make sense to poetically describe a ball or any other spherical object like a fruit?

Comment: @Lesley I’m not asking you to change your answer, I’m asking how come the Creator when He uses poetry is allowed to be inaccurate and misleading about certain details about the physical world we live in. Why does poetry trump facts? Saying the earth and it’s margins are like a wax seal is different than describing a spherical ball. Or am I misreading your answer, you are saying that He is being accurate and the earth is flat like a wax seal?

Comment: The poetic language of the Hebrew scriptures was not a problem to the ancients back then; it is to us today because we try to inflict modern points of view upon it. The readers of the book of Job etc, reading in ancient Hebrew, would 'get it'; but we do the literature a dis-service if we take modern arguments about the shape of the earth and try to squeeze them into the text. Context shows the poetry of barring the sea as the wicked are contained. It's not about the shape of the planet. God's poetry eclipses ours - we need to look to Him to understand and jettison our interpretations. Yes?

Comment: @Mr Constantin – I would never dare to presume to speak for God.  It’s how humans interpret God’s words that I question.  And no, I am NOT suggesting that God is saying the earth is literally like a flat, wax seal.  However, I can use my artistic eye to see how the sun rising over a mountainous landscape effects visual illusions that could be LIKENED to the contours of a wax seal.  Who am I to question God?  Job tried it and was shot down in flames (not literal flames, you understand – that’s a figure of speech).  Peace to you.

Comment: P.S. Ever seen hot wax poured over a rounded object? It follows the contours of the shape it covers, and if the surface is irregular, then the wax, after it cools, likewise becomes irregular.  The wax follows the contours of the surface upon which it is poured.  The wax is flexible and fluid, till it cools. I think God knows what he's talking about - it's just humans who try to read too much into stuff.

Comment: I don’t know why you are talking about a globe. Until the 16th century no one was talking about a globe except a few philosophers in Greece but certainly no one in the Middle East at the time of Job. A globe view is a relatively new concept. That passage is clearly taking about a flat earth. It’s sounds to me a little like cognitive dissonance, is what it sounds like to me. Also mountains all around, what about the waters that they are holding? All the information in the text needs to be accounted for. I don’t know of any historian that would deny this passage is describing a flat earth.

Comment: @Anne are you saying that just because we cannot comprehend the poetry, that we cannot apprehend it either? Then you are making my point, the Creator is communicating something irrelevant and hence misleading. And yet I cannot fathom the idea that He would lie nor that He would go along with a flat earth if He knows otherwise. But you seem to be suggesting that if it’s poetic then it doesn’t have to correspond to reality. So He is making a point about facts in nature that can be verified but mixing in fiction to do what exactly? I have never sent a seal pressed into wax and out comes a globe

Comment: Aristotle evidenced a spherical Earth in 330 BC. In 240 BC, Eratosthenes calculated the Earth’s spherical circumference. In his treatise The reckoning of time, the venerable Bede (c.672 – 735 AD) explained the varying duration of daylight in terms of ‘the roundness of the earth… for not without reason is it called “the orb of the world” on the pages of Holy Scripture and of ordinary literature. It is, in fact, set like a sphere in the middle of the whole universe.’ Bede was required reading for priests then. Yes, mediaeval scholars expressed flat-Earth beliefs, but Jeffrey Russell (professor

Comment: of history at University of California, Santa Barbara) shows in his book 'Inventing The Flat Earth: Columbus and modern historians', that the flat-Earth theory is little more than a fable used to denigrate pre-modern European civilization.

I am saying that once we comprehend the poetry God’s words to Job are fabulously tailored to the situation obtaining back then. The ancients could see the shape of the moon, that the shadow of Earth on the Moon is always circular, and that only a spherical Earth could cast a circular shadow at all lunar phases. Southbound travellers saw southern stars

Comment: rising higher above the horizon. They accurately calculated movements of the heavenly bodies but had they held to a flat earth concept, they could not have done that. Poetry relates to reality even if it uses apparently unrelated concepts – to make a point. The poetic point was about barring the sea as the wicked are contained. I’m not going to say any more on this here as you seem to have a bee in your bonnet regarding this. But I appreciate and note your view.

Answer (score 1):

All commentaries I have read seem to agree that the seal here is in reference to the earth. They make the point that the earth is formed as clay underneath the seal as it is turned, alluding to the rolling cylinder seal, such as is found in Babylon, which leaves it’s impressions on the clay.

However, my answer to your question is no.  In my opinion, the clay seal here does not pertain to the earth.  I think looking at this verse in context, as being a reference to Christ, provides a better understanding of the text.

***12 Hast thou commanded the morning since thy days; and caused the dayspring to know his place;***

The term **dayspring**, the dawning of the sun, is personified here (his place).

The only other occurrence of the term “dayspring” in the bible is found in Luke 1:78-79.  There Zacharias, in prophesying the arrival of Christ, said the following:

> Through the tender mercy of our God; Whereby the dayspring from on
> high hath visited us, To give light to them that sit in darkness and
> in the shadow of death, To guide our feet into the way of peace.

I suggest that the dayspring in Job refers to Christ and the fact that God established the purpose and position of Christ.

***13 That it might take hold of the ends of the earth, that the wicked might be shaken out of it?***

Since God is making reference to the “ends of the earth” some have speculated that he could be saying that the earth is flat and has actual ends.  However, this is just a figure of speech.   The main point is that the first occurrence of “it” here is referring back to the dayspring, and how he will separate out the wicked from the face of the earth.

John may be referencing this verse when he says of Jesus as he approaches the River Jordan in Matthew 3:12

> “Whose fan is in his hand, and he will thoroughly purge his floor, and
> gather his wheat into the garner; but he will burn up the chaff with
> unquenchable fire. “

The fan referred to here is the winnowing basket that is used to purify grain.  The act of taking hold of the ends of the earth and the fan is a picture of how all are confined in Christ’s hand and none will escape his judgment.

***14 It is turned as clay to the seal; and they stand as a garment.***

Most commentators seem to say that the mountains are what stand in relief like the folds in a garment whose relief is revealed by the dawning sun.

But in my opinion, the word “It” in vs14 does not refer to the earth, it again refers back to the dayspring in vs12, still a reference to Christ.  It is Christ, in an earthly body of clay, who is stamped out as a perfect image of God like a royal seal is used to impress a duplicate image in clay to indicate the approval of the king.   See Colossians 1:15 in reference to Christ

> “Who is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of every
> creature.”

And, as a result, God the Father and Christ are bound and stand together as a woven garment.  This may help explain John 19:23–24, quoting Psalm 22:18–19, in reference to Christ, that his vesture was woven as a single piece and, as a result, was not parted.

Also see the opening to the book of Hebrews, Chapter 1:1-3, which may refer back to this passage in Job:

> God, who at sundry times and in divers manners spake in time past unto
> the fathers by the prophets, Hath in these last days spoken unto us by
> his Son, whom he hath appointed heir of all things (**caused the
> dayspring to know his place)**, by whom also he made the worlds; Who
> being the brightness of his glory (**the dayspring**), and the express
> image of his person (**turned as clay to the seal**), and upholding all
> things (**stand as a garment**) by the word of his power...

***15 And from the wicked their light is withholden, and the high arm shall be broken.***

“Their” here refers to God the Father and Christ.  Although Christ brings light to those that sit in the shadow of darkness and long for the light, the pride of the wicked will be brought low.

Comment: *”This is just a figure of speech”*, how do you know? Are you imposing a modern cosmological ideology onto the text? That’s no longer hermeneutics, that’s personal bias. You started off well, accepting the Scriptures as they are written and then you let your opinions color the text, dismissing the words with a simple, “it’s figurative speech”. You ought to test your assumptions. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 1):

How can one not see that he is talking about the shape of the earth. The Earth takes shape like clay under a seal. That is solidly saying the earth is flat with its features showing. I'm no expert just a simple mind that's why I believe God said what he said as he meant it so that even the simple minds could understand his words. Everyone wants to interpret what he is saying to fit their narrative or beliefs.I do not question God or his words or meanings of his words I do however question everything man says. Has anyone asked God? I doubt it! Would anyone say that the 10 commandments means anything other than what they mean as written? No so why would God say some things just as he meant and others we would have to interpret and guess at? He wouldn't and it's ridiculous to think he would. I'm not here to push anything onto anyone or change ones beliefs I'm just saying what I hear from a simple mind perspective.
Glory be to God the Alpha and the Omega!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.